# Confusion on Basic Logic Question about Contrapositive (simple probably)

Tags: logic, solution-verification

So, suppose we are told to show the statement: "If $\frac{1}{x}$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational."

This seems pretty clearly true, and I can't think of a counterexample, but when we consider the logically equivalent contrapositive: "If $x$ is rational, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is rational." we see that this statement is untrue for $x=0$. Does this imply the original statement is also false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A statement involving $\frac1x$ is not *untrue* for $x=0$, it is *ill-formed* because part of it is not defined (namely $\frac10$). An ill-formed sentence doesn't have a defined truth value.

However, we sometimes interpret a sentence like "if $x$ is rational, then $\frac1x$ is rational" as having an implicit quantifier like "for all real  numbers $x\ne0$, ..." so that its truth value doesn't depend on the cases where subexpressions are undefined. Doing this resolves your problem, making the original sentence and the contrapositive version both true.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $\frac{1}{x}$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational
2. If $x$ is rational, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is rational

implicitly means:

1. **For every** $\boldsymbol x,$ if $\frac{1}{x}$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational
2. **For every** $\boldsymbol x,$ if $x$ is rational, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is rational.

But what exactly does “every $x$” mean? Is $7+4i$ a candidate of “every $x$”? Is $0$ a candidate of “every $x$”? Part of the context of every statement is a (generally tacit) discourse domain:

- **when the discourse domain is** $\boldsymbol{\mathbb R{\setminus}\{0\}},$ then both statements are true;
- **when the discourse domain is** $\boldsymbol{\mathbb R},$ then $\frac10$ being rational/irrational is non-meaningful, so technically both statements are neither true nor false; alternatively, we can *informally* say that $\frac10$ being rational/irrational is false, in which case Statement 1 is true while Statement 2 is false;
- **when the discourse domain is** $\boldsymbol{\mathbb C},$ and when the set of irrationals is defined as $\mathbb R{\setminus}\mathbb Q$ (this is yet another piece of the context), then “$7+4i$ is rational” and “$7+4i$ is irrational” are both false.